# mapstruct mapping Entity OneToMany to DTO and reverse

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm trying to use a [mapstruct](http://mapstruct.org) and I need to mapping `Entity` with a sub `Entity` list, I have relationship `oneToMany` and `manyToOne` and I need to mapping in both cases:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class EmailEntity {

private int id;  

... // some fields

@ManyToOne
private DeliveredEmailInfoEntity deliveredEmailInfo;

}
```

.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class DeliveredEmailInfoEntity {

private int id;

... // some fields  

@OneToMany
private List<EmailEntity> emails;

}
```

mapping to:

```
@Data
public class EmailDTO {

private int id;  

... // some fields

private DeliveredEmailInfoDTO deliveredEmailInfo;

}
```

.

```
@Data
public class DeliveredEmailInfoDTO {

private int id;

... // some fields  

private List<EmailDTO> emails;

}
```

How to do it in the best way ?

Comment: Is your issue the cyclic dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Also see other answer)

It should be straightforward, there is nothing challenging in your case:

```
@Mapper
public interface EmailInfoMapper {

    EmailDTO entityToDTO(EmailEntity duration);
    EmailEntity dtoToEntity(EmailDTO price);

    DeliveredEmailInfoDTO entityToDTO(DeliveredEmailInfoEntity duration);
    DeliveredEmailInfoEntity dtoToEntity(DeliveredEmailInfoDTO price);
}
```

You should include your mapper in your question and what the problem you have with it.

Comment: This example can lead to cyclic interdependence and ultimately to stack overflow exception. I'd propose a solution below, which helps to avoid such bottlenecks.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid infinite cross setting of nested fields you should limit this dependency, for example on the second nested level, i.e. your root `EmailDTO` will have one nested `DeliveredEmailInfoDTO` object (many-to-one relationship), while your root `DeliveredEmailInfoDTO` will have the list of nested `EmailDTO` objects (one-to-many relationship) and nothing on the next nesting level:

```
@Mapper(uses = DeliveredEmailInfoMapper.class)
public interface EmailMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "deliveredEmailInfo.emails", ignore = true)
    EmailDTO toDTO(EmailEntity entity);

    // other methods omitted 

    @Named("emailDTOList")
    default List<EmailDTO> toEmailDTOList(List<EmailEntity> source) {
        return source
                .stream()
                .map(this::toDTO)
                .peek(dto -> dto.setDeliveredEmailInfo(null))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

@Mapper(uses = EmailMapper.class)
public interface DeliveredEmailInfoMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "emails", source = "emails", qualifiedByName = "emailDTOList")
    DeliveredEmailInfoDTO toDTO(DeliveredEmailInfoEntity entity);

    // other methods omitted 

}
```